# How to git clone dotfiles into my home directory with one command?

Tags: git, bash

When you do a typical "git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git" you get a folder in the current directory with all the files found in that directory.

What I'm looking for is an optional command line arg that lets you drop all the files from that git repo (including the .git itself) in the directory you issue the clone command from.

I'm using bash if that is a concern -thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean `git clone repo .`, the last `.` meaning 'current dir'?

Comment: When I do that I always get this error => fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory. **using Xubuntu 12.10

Comment: Well yep _"Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty."_ .... So, if you want it in a non-empty dir... There is no cli arg for that. You can `mv` all you like after though, but it will probably very easy to break the git functionality then...

Comment: thanks -I didn't think that option existed (just wanted to be sure)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I see what you want.
You can init a git repository to your home directory then add a remote origin and pull.

```
cd
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/foo/bar.git
git pull
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this solution? (compared to `git clone url .`) ?

Comment: `fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the dot `.` ?

```
git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git .
```

From the git clone man page:

```
git clone [--template=<template_directory>]
          [-l] [-s] [--no-hardlinks] [-q] [-n] [--bare] [--mirror]
          [-o <name>] [-b <name>] [-u <upload-pack>] [--reference <repository>]
          [--separate-git-dir <git dir>]
          [--depth <depth>] [--recursive|--recurse-submodules] [--] <repository>
          [<directory>]
```

Where (target)directory is the last argument. Note that you have to make sure that the current folder `.` is empty